# Limiting the output

Tags: python, regex

I made a dictionary using .groupdict() function, however, I am having a problem regarding elimination of certain output dictionaries.
For example my code looks like this (tweet is a string that contains 5 elements separated by || :

```
 def somefuntion(pattern,tweet):
    pattern = "^(?P<username>.*?)(?:\|{2}[^|]+){2}\|{2}(?P<botprob>.*?)(?:\|{2}|$)"
      for paper in tweet:
         for item in re.finditer(pattern,paper):
              item.groupdict()
```

This produces an output in the form:

```
{'username': 'yashrgupta ', 'botprob': ' 0.30794588629999997 '}
{'username': 'sterector ', 'botprob': ' 0.39391528649999996 '}
{'username': 'MalcolmXon ', 'botprob': ' 0.05630123819 '}
{'username': 'ryechuuuuu ', 'botprob': ' 0.08492567222000001 '}
{'username': 'dpsisi ', 'botprob': ' 0.8300337045 '}
```

But I would like it to only return dictionaries whose botprob is above 0.7. How do I do this?

Comment: You can filter the obtained dictionaries. No need to make your regex even more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, as @WiktorStribizew notes, just skip iterations you don't want:

```py
pattern = "^(?P<username>.*?)(?:\|{2}[^|]+){2}\|{2}(?P<botprob>.*?)(?:\|{2}|$)"
  for paper in tweet:
     for item in re.finditer(pattern,paper):
          item = item.groupdict()
          if item["botprob"] < 0.7:
              continue
          print(item)
```

This could be wrapped in a generator expression to save the explicit `continue`, but there's enough going on as it is without making it harder to read (in this case).

**UPDATE** since you are apparently in a function:

```py
pattern = "^(?P<username>.*?)(?:\|{2}[^|]+){2}\|{2}(?P<botprob>.*?)(?:\|{2}|$)"
  items = []
  for paper in tweet:
     for item in re.finditer(pattern,paper):
          item = item.groupdict()
          if float(item["botprob"]) > 0.7:
              items.append(item)
              
  return items
```

Or using comprehensions:

```py
groupdicts = (item.groupdict() for paper in tweet for item in re.finditer(pattern, paper))
return [item for item in groupdicts if float(item["botprob"]) > 0.7]
```

Comment: Still returns all the values :(

Comment: I've added an explicit print statement which might clarify things.  If you want to *return* value, rather than processing them immediately, it would help if you updated your question to say so.  (The same approach is valid, but it's written slightly differently)

Comment: Ok updated it, sorry for the confusion. I made an else if statement in the form of for paper in tweet:
     for item in re.finditer(pattern,paper):
          item =item.groupdict()
          if item["botprob"]<0.7:
            continue
          else:
            return item now but it still doesnt work

Comment: @FafamKurac123 see updated post.  You're *nearly* there, but you give up after returning one item.  You would want to assign correct items to a list and return that, but I think this kind of filtering operation is better written as a bunch of generator comprehensions terminating in a list comprehension.

Comment: Now it produces a 'callable-iterator' object has no attribute 'groupdict' error. Why are there so many complications with this one :(

Comment: Yeah I'm not very awake today.  On reflection the imperative soln is probably clearest (see update *again*).  However I'll add the generator in in a mo

Comment: Hey, it still won't work. I am getting really frustrated with this. The code makes perfect sense but it just doesn't want to work. :(((((((((((

Comment: It prints out the values which are smaller than 0.7 despite going through the if statement.

Comment: Nevermind, I just ahd to put the item["botprob"] into float(), Thanks for everything <3

Comment: @FafamKuraz today is not my brightest day; I even checked if they were strings as they were green... but the space caused me to miss the `'`.  Glad you caught it

Answer (score 0):

> I would like it to only return dictionaries whose botprob is above 0.7.

```
entries = [{'username': 'yashrgupta ', 'botprob': ' 0.30794588629999997 '},
           {'username': 'sterector ', 'botprob': ' 0.39391528649999996 '},
           {'username': 'MalcolmXon ', 'botprob': ' 0.05630123819 '},
           {'username': 'ryechuuuuu ', 'botprob': ' 0.08492567222000001 '},
           {'username': 'dpsisi ', 'botprob': ' 0.8300337045 '}]

filtered_entries = [e for e in entries if float(e['botprob'].strip()) > 0.7]
print(filtered_entries)
```

output

```
[{'username': 'dpsisi ', 'botprob': ' 0.8300337045 '}]
```